# How to display project name in minimized Xcode?

Tags: xcode

When Xcode project window is collapsed to dock it shows name of the current file:
[image]

Is there any way to customize Xcode, so it will show project name in the dock, or "project_name - file_name"?

Comment: I suppose you could click on the project name in the `Project Navigator` before minimizing it so it shows it in the dock, or create a script that does it for you.

Comment: And how should I remember the last file I work with?

Comment: Use the **<** `Go Back` button in XCode, it should take you right to it.

Comment: Well, it's not simpler then just open that window and see the project name :)